# smaller finite value double - Java

Tags: java, double

I am learning new things about Java and I came across the question: what is the smallest finite value of type `double`? Is the answer `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`?

Answer (score 3):

`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is **not** a finite value, so it can't be the smallest finite value of type double.

`Double.MIN_VALUE` is also **not** the smallest finite value of type double, since that's the

> smallest **positive** nonzero value of type double

The smallest finite value of type double is `-Double.MAX_VALUE`, whose value is `-1.79769313348623157E308`, or -(2-2<sup>-52</sup>)*2<sup>1023</sup> or `Double.longBitsToDouble(0xffefffffffffffffL)`.

This can be calculated based on [JLS 4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3):

> The finite nonzero values of any floating-point value set can all be expressed in the form s ⋅ m ⋅ 2<sup>(e - N + 1)</sup>, where s is +1 or -1, m is a positive integer less than 2<sup>N</sup>, and e is an integer between Emin = -(2<sup>K-1</sup>-2) and Emax = 2<sup>K-1</sup>-1, inclusive.

For `double`, `Emax==1023` and `N==53`.

When you assign in s ⋅ m ⋅ 2<sup>(e - N + 1)</sup> the values s=-1, m=2<sup>N</sup>-1 and e = Emax, you get the minimum finite value: -1 * (2<sup>53</sup>-1)*2<sup>(1023 - 53 + 1)</sup> = - (2 - 2<sup>-52</sup>) * 2<sup>1023</sup>.

Comment: There's a typo: `The smallest finite value of type double is -Double.MIN_VALUE`, should be `-Double.MAX_VALUE`, the number then given as -1.7976931348623157E308 is correct.

Comment: @Ralf thanks. I can't believe I made this typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The finite range of double is 4.9E-324 to 1.7e+038. Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY is just a contant the is defined by the [ieee floating point specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity)

> public static final double NEGATIVE_INFINITY
>
> A constant holding the negative infinity of type double. It is equal
> to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L)

Answer (score 0):

The smallest positive finite non-zero value of type double is 4.9e-324.
The smallest negative finite value is -1.7976931348623157E308.
You can refer to [Java Language Specification of double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).